# Using Asterisk with multiple phone lines (PSTN)

Tags: voip, pbx, telecommunication

I've had experience working with Asterisk over VoIP. Did pretty complex stuff with it as long as it had ethernet cables and internet connected. I've gotten used to connecting the box to an ITSP and getting DIDs pointed to the server and each DID allowing multiple channels over that connection. My ITSP provided "unlimited channels" so that worked fine. All calls came into Asterisk, no matter what.

Now, I'm trying to do the same with PSTN and it's hard to follow. Basically, I'm looking to have Asterisk PBX in my company and take in one PSTN phone number. And have this "multiple channels" thing enabled. The incoming call will have such options as listening to a recording (FAQ style), or routing to extensions, or leaving voicemails - basic stuff. If the caller hears a recording, that occupies one channel. I'd be having more callers listening to these recordings, IVR routing them to extensions, letting them leave voicemails and ofcourse, outbound calls (routed out through the PSTN connection for landlines and to a GSM gateway for mobiles).

So with these requirements in mind, I keep thinking that it will be similar to the VoIP infrastructure I have experience with where I tell the PSTN company "yo, give me one number and let me get/send unlimited calls on it". I'm afraid there's some kind of a technical limitation to that.

Ofcourse, my aim is to not have too many of these phone numbers (or lines?) because each of these lines will cost extra money. 
So... what do you think? How do you think I should go about this?

PS: My PSTN is called PLDT -> http://www.pldtsme-nation.com.ph/LM/products.html
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Mark, welcome - this is a Q&A forum for specific questions.  Your question appears to be inviting a discussion, which is not its purpose.  The FAQ is here http://superuser.com/faq.

Comment: Sorry, I came here from Google because someone else had a similar question - except with SIP, instead of PSTN. And I clicked "Ask Question" and I went to town. 

Any way I can move this?

Comment: This person is asking for something, while quite doable, requires basically a tutorial on Asterisk, trunking, inbound/outbound-routing and extension and endpoint building.  Possibly not ideal for here.  Google for tutorials for whatever flavour of Asterisk build/distro you're using.